# Get list of current page's categories in MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki, categories

I'm trying to display a page's categories in my MediaWiki skin without resorting to the following default code:

```
<?php if ( $this->data['catlinks'] ) { $this->html( 'catlinks' ); } ?>
```

Which adds a bunch of unnecessary HTML that I do not want.

```
<div id='catlinks' class='catlinks'>
    <div id="mw-normal-catlinks" class="mw-normal-catlinks">
        <a href="/wiki/Special:Categories" title="Special:Categories">Category</a>: 
        <ul><li><a href="/w/index.php?title=Category:Player_Character&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Category:Player Character (page does not exist)">Player Character</a></li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ideally I would just get the category names as plain text or an array, but I don't want to extrapolate them from the HTML that is returned by the code above.

**How can I echo a MediaWiki page's categories as plain text?**

---

**Update:**

I'm using this code to generate category breadcrumbs for my Wiki. Starting with the most top-level category and working it's way down. (Not tested excessively). Please note this is probably very hacky and would be better as an Extension.

```
    // Get the current page's Title
    $wiki_title = $this->data['skin']->getTitle();
    // Get the categories
    $parenttree = $wiki_title->getParentCategoryTree();

    // Skin object passed by reference cause it can not be
    // accessed under the method subfunction drawCategoryBrowser
    $tempout = explode( "\n", $this->data['skin']->drawCategoryBrowser( $parenttree ) );
    // Convert data to usable array
    $wiki_category_breadcrumbs = explode( "&gt;", $tempout[1]);

    // Returns every category as URL with <li> tags wrapped around it
    foreach( $wiki_category_breadcrumbs as $value ) {           
        echo "<li>". $value ."</li>";
    }
```

Comment: what do you expect for the output?

Comment: I'm planning to store the categories in a variable and then I will use that to generate breadcrumbs and add category-specific classes to certain elements. So it could be anything from plain text to an array.

Comment: What is `$this`? Last I checked there were a couple of different methods for building skins; can you include some more detail?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what `$this` references to. (Probably the reason why I have such a hard time grabbing data.) You can see in what context it is used in a skin on this page: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skinning/Archive#Initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that categories are only available as html, is one of the weirder parts of MediaWiki skinning. It should still be possible to fetch them as an array, though. Depending on where in the skin code you are (you don't tell us what `$this` refers to), these (untested) snippets should probably do the job:

**From the `execute()`-function:**

```
$title = $this->data['skin']->getTitle();
$categories = $title->getParentCategories();
```

**From the `initPage()`-function:**

```
$title = $this->getTitle();
$categories = $title->getParentCategories();
```

Comment: The first example worked for me. With some custom code I can now grab data (such as categories) and use it in my skin however I want. I will update my question with my code once I have completed it. Thank you so much!